# Does anyone know how i would convert this command into a on message command

Tags: python, discord.py

Here Is My Code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def banall(ctx):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        for user in list(ctx.guild.members):
            try:
                await ctx.guild.ban(user)
                await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has been banned from {ctx.guild.name}")
                
            except:
                await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has FAILED to be banned from {ctx.guild.name}")
```

I'm trying to make it so when someone says "banall" it will ban all the members in the server. I found have found this command works but with for example !banall" and I want to get rid of the "!" and so it will just be "banall". Does anyone know how I would go about doing this. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Adapt the command to work with `on_message()`. This can be done by removing the method decorator (`@client.command(pass_context=True)`) and changing `ctx` to message since the `on_message()` function gets a `message` object.

```py
async def banall(message):
    await message.delete()
    for user in list(message.guild.members):
        try:
            await message.guild.ban(user)
            await message.channel.send(f"{user.name} has been banned from {message.guild.name}")       
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has FAILED to be banned from {ctx.guild.name}")
```

2. Run the function within the `on_message()`. This can be done with an if statement to check whether the message's content is "banall".

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "banall":
        await banall(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut the "!" from "!banall" you need to do this:

```
string = "!banall"
string2 = string.replace('!', '')
```

Comment: `discord.py` has a command handler that runs a function (such as this one) when it receives a command with a prefix defined in code. That's why OP is trying to run the function inside `on_message()` so the command doesn't require a prefix. You can find more information about `discord.py`'s command handler here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: So OP want's to have it so that when someone enters "banall" something happens and not just "!banall"?